# MySQL is too slow to execute query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table "user_values" with over 20 milion rows.
The table is like this:

```
id | user_id |      scan_date      | value | category |      user_date      | 

1  |    1    | 2016-12-10 10:10:10 |  10   |    1     | 2016-01-05 11:11:11 | 
2  |    2    | 2016-12-10 10:10:10 |  14   |    2     | 2016-02-06 12:12:12 | 
3  |    3    | 2016-12-10 10:10:10 |  15   |    2     | 2016-03-07 13:13:13 | 
4  |    1    | 2016-12-10 12:10:10 |  11   |    1     | 2016-01-05 10:10:10 | 
5  |    2    | 2016-12-10 12:10:10 |  13   |    2     | 2016-02-06 12:12:12 | 
6  |    3    | 2016-12-10 12:10:10 |  17   |    2     | 2016-03-07 13:13:13 | 
7  |    1    | 2016-12-10 14:10:10 |  13   |    1     | 2016-01-05 11:11:11 | 
8  |    2    | 2016-12-10 14:10:10 |  15   |    2     | 2016-02-06 12:12:12 | 
9  |    3    | 2016-12-10 14:10:10 |  16   |    2     | 2016-03-07 13:13:13 | 
10 |    1    | 2016-12-10 16:10:10 |  18   |    1     | 2016-01-05 11:11:11 | 
11 |    2    | 2016-12-10 16:10:10 |  13   |    2     | 2016-02-06 12:12:12 | 
12 |    3    | 2016-12-10 16:10:10 |  14   |    2     | 2016-03-07 13:13:13 |
```

The "scan_date" is when the row is written.

Mysql write about 1 milion of rows in this table every day.

I have a SELECT QUERY to get the last 'value' for every user:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM user_values 
        WHERE
        category =  '2' AND
        user_date      >=  '2016-01-16' AND
        user_date      <= '2016-12-15 10:34:35' 
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 999999999) as user_values
        WHERE 
        category = '2' AND
        user_date      >=  '2016-01-16' AND
        user_date      <= '2016-12-15 10:34:35' 
        GROUP BY user_values.user_id
```

The query is the faster that i found but now i get the error "MySQL server has gone away" because the query is too slow.

I also tried to create partitions: 100 partitions by hash(id) but i didn't resolved, i think is slower now.

Someone suggests to me to buy a powerful server but i think that i don't resolve the problem.
Someone suggests to me to create a mysql "cluster" master/slave.

Have you an other suggest or a better query or a better mysql configuration?

Comment: Any indexes on 20m rows?

Comment: Yes! I have index on "scan_date", "category","user_date" and "user_id"

Comment: Can you post the result of `EXPLAIN <Your Query>`

Comment: Sorry i can't. MySql says "MySQL server has gone away"

Comment: That is not the kind of thing the MySQL server would report, that is a tool you're using to connect to the database. You can do the explain plan with a limit of a hundred records for example, that should reduce the runtime of the query enough that it won't time out.

Comment: i used explain on a identical table ma with less rows. i posted the results in the last answer of this post

Answer (score 0):

get last insert id from database in **mysqli**

```
$sql = "YOUR INSERT QUERY";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
}
```

**Get value using last user id**

```
$sql2 = "SELECT `value` FROM tablename where `id`=$last_id ; 
$value = $conn->query($sql2);
echo "Value of last user is $value"
```

**Get Last insert id by PDO**

```
    $sql = "YOUR INSERT QUERY";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

**Get value using last user id**

```
$sql2 = "SELECT `value` FROM tablename where `id`=$last_id ; 
$value = $conn->query($sql2);
echo "Value of last user is $value"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
id | select_type | table      | type| possible_keys      | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                                       |
1  |  PRIMARY    | <derived2> | ALL | NULL               | NULL     | NULL    | NULL  | 53604| 100.00   | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort|

2  |  DERIVED    |users_values| ref | category,user_date | category | 4       | const | 53604| 100.00   | Using where; Using filesort
```